Starting application using cmnd "dotnet" fails, using .exe works
I have a small .Net 7.0 application, that needs to run on both windows and linux. The application needs to call a 32-bit dll using pinvoke, so targeting portable is no option. the application os configured with the platform-targets ARM32 and x86:
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Platforms>ARM32;x86</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>

all parts of the application have this configuration. when i start the application via VS 2022 or Rider, it runs as expected on my windows machine. If i try tu start the build-output from bin, or a release-build of the application using the "dotnet" command, it fails.
Release-Config:

Exception:

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
or assembly 'EIS.Host, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null'.

EIS.Host is the name of the Startup-project that starts the application. The exe that gets created also is called "EIS.Host.exe"
I have tried different config, like adding this to csproj:
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

after that i switched to the current config.
i tried builds with rider and vs2022. i tried starting the build-output and release-output both for arm32 and x86 via dotnet (x86 directly on my machine, arm32 using wsl2)

It's doubtful p/invoke will work on linux for Windows dlls, though you might get lucky if WINE is working on the system. It's also doubtful a windows dll compiled for x86/64 will work on ARM at all, WINE or not.

Type "where dotnet.exe" at the command prompt.  Good odds you'll see it in c:\program files\dotnet, the home of the 64-bit install of .net.  Use "c:\program files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" instead.

I couldn't find MSBuild Property called Platforms (e.g. it's not here). Are you sure such Property exists? I could only find Platform. Maybe IDEs are able to parse such property, but the dotnet command is unable to.
I would first try that. If that's the case, you can create two project files, one for linux and the other for windows architecture. After that configured, you can than try to put it into one project file.
If it's still not working, try to remove the pinvoke call and than remove all unnecessary configuration in the project file that you added only because of the pinvoke. Just to get it into state where you are able to build the project using dotnet build. After that, try to add pinvoke code and project config only e.g. for windows architecture and again try to build with dotnet. Do it in this iterative fashion in order to better locate where exactly is the problem. (You can also have problems with dotnet cli itself!).
You can also try to delete all bin and obj files manually. Sometimes dotnet clean doesn't remove all .dlls, resulting in unexpected errors during build.

splitting it into two projectfiles solved the problem, thx
